Stata command to build a graph showing for mixed effects linear regression models
What is the step by step cpde to build a graph reflecting mixed effects linear regression model for age and gender as fixed effect and weight as the response using Stata?
mixed Weight age_Months i.Gender || Cod_IndHosp : , covariance(unstructured) 
est store Model1
margins, dydx(age_Months Gender)

and the problem starts from here
 xtitle("Age in Months") ytitle("Weight") title("Marginal Means of Weight by Gender and Age")
command xtitle is unrecognized
r(199);

twoway (line age_Months if Gender==0, color(red) legend(label(1 "Male"))) ///
too few variables specified
r(102);

(line age_Months if Gender==1, color(blue) legend(label(2 "Female"))), ///
( is not a valid command name
r(199);

xtitle("Age in Months") ytitle("Weight") title("Marginal Means of Weight by Gender and Age")
command xtitle is unrecognized
r(199);


Questions that are just a list of minor errors and lack reproducible code aren't good questions for Stack Overflow. If you're a beginner, that's fine, but there is no way to learn except repeated reference to the documentation. Don't use ChatGPT or other AI.

There are at least three problems here.
1.
line age_Months

You are specifying one variable; line needs at least two variables, one x variable (which should come last) and at least one y variable.
Evidently you need to specify Weight too.
2.
(line age_Months

The same problem, except that Stata chokes on ( which may not start a command. You could omit it; or as in other code start with twoway.
3.
xtitle("Age in Months") 

is an option and must be part of a legal command on one logical line. As the error message indicates, Stata is expecting a command to start the logical line and xtitle() is not a command. (Other software may allow you to modify an existing graph by issuing additional syntax, but Stata doesn't work like that.)
There may be other problems, but as you don't give a minimal reproducible example, it's not possible to run your code without inventing suitable data.
Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for much more guidance.

Noted, even removing the parenthesis the code is given error, see below.
twoway age_Months if Gender==0, color(red) legend(label(0 "Male"))) ///age_Months is not a twoway plot type
r(198);
age_Months if Gender==1, color(blue) legend(label(1 "Female"))), ///
command age_Months is unrecognized
r(199);
.
xtitle "Age in Months" ytitle("Weight") title("Marginal Means of Weight by Gender and Age")command xtitle is unrecognized
r(199);

Code is hard to read in comments without backticks mark-up. One new  error is that  you need twoway line and that needs to be followed by two variable  names  Another new error is that the numbers in label() can't be zero. Otherwise the problems appear to be errors already explained in my answer.
